# Using PL/Python in Cloud SQL Postgres for trigger functions

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm wondering if Cloud SQL has support for procedural languages other than PL/PgSQL? If I try to create a function using python I get an error "Unable to resolve language 'plpython3u'". I can create functions with regular SQL procedural although there's also no documentation on that being supported in Cloud SQL.

Comment: This is not supported at the moment. You may file for a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if your use case requires it.